# Speed Up Matching program in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, performance

I am writing a VBA code on excel using loops to go through **10000+ lines**.

Here is an example of the table

[image: Table_Matching_Example]

And here is the code I wrote :

```
Sub Find_Matches()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xrow As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets("Data").Activate

    tCnt = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim e, f, a, j, h As Range
    xrow = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    For xrow = 2 To tCnt Step 1
        Set e = Range("E" & xrow)
        Set f = e.Offset(0, 1)
        Set a = e.Offset(0, -4)
        Set j = e.Offset(0, 5)
        Set h = e.Offset(0, 3)
        For Each Cell In Range("E2:E" & tCnt)
            If Cell.Value = e.Value Then
                If Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Value Then
                    If Cell.Offset(0, -4).Value = a.Value Then
                        If Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = j.Value Then
                            If Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = h.Value Then
                                If (e.Offset(0, 7).Value) + (Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value) = 0 Then
                                    Cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                                    e.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

As you can imagine, this is taking a lot of time to go through 10000+ lines and I would like to find a faster solution. There must be a method I don't think to avoid the *over looping*

Here are the condition :

> For each line, if another line anywhere in the file has the exact same
>   :
>
> - Buyer ID (col. E)
> - `# purchased (col. F)
> - Product ID (col.A)
> - Payment (col. J)
> - Date purchased (col. H)
>
> Then, if the SUM of the Amount (col. L) the those two matching line is
>   0, then color both rows in yellow.
>
> *Note that extra columns are present and not being compared (eg- col. B) but are still important for the document and cannot be deleted to ease the process.*

Running the previous code, in my example, row 2 & 5 get highlighted :
[image: Table_After_Running]

Comment: If your code already works this might be better a question for [Stack Exchange: Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note that when you Dim'med your variables, only h was a Range. All the others (e,f,a,j) were variants. You need to write "As Range" after every one of them. Regarding the speed - have you tried copying all the cells into a 2D array before looping through the array? Working with arrays is faster than continually interacting with worksheets.

Comment: No, I have not. This is exactly the kind of input I am looking for : "what have I not thought of ?" Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ
I wouldn't say the code is working per se as it is unusuable because too slow. it only meets the conditions stated. If you think it's still considered as working and should go to Stack Exchange, I will happily transfer the post over there!

Comment: You have a number of undeclared variables. Also, you refer to `p` and it doesn't appear to be setup anywhere.  Add 'Option Explicit` to the top of [avery] module [always] to help you locate issues. There may be other issues, I'm not sure

Comment: "fasten" means "close or do up securely." It doesn't mean speed up.

Comment: Yes @ashleedawg, sorry, it's because I edited the original table and code before posting. Those p were leftovers. Edited in the post !

Comment: Your right @Enigmativity: editing the title.

Comment: @AlexBrollo - LOL "your" should be "you're". ;-)

Comment: Wow. Damned, this one is a big one SORRY! You ARE right.=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using nested dictionaries and arrays to check all conditions

Timer with my test data: **`Rows: 100,001; Dupes: 70,000 - Time: 14.217 sec`**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindMatches()
    Const E = 5, F = 6, A = 1, J = 10, H = 8, L = 12

    Dim ur As Range, x As Variant, ub As Long, d As Object, found As Object

    Set ur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange
    x = ur
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set found = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim r As Long, rId As String, itm As Variant, dupeRows As Object

    For r = ur.Row To ur.Rows.Count
        rId = x(r, E) & x(r, F) & x(r, A) & x(r, J) & x(r, H)
        If Not d.Exists(rId) Then
            Set dupeRows = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dupeRows(r) = 0
            Set d(rId) = dupeRows
        Else
            For Each itm In d(rId)
                If x(r, L) + x(itm, L) = 0 Then
                    found(r) = 0
                    found(itm) = 0
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each itm In found
        ur.Range("A" & itm).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

Comment: Yes, Thank you! That's a really cool solution and way around. My method was too straight forward (if then if then if then...) and this one is just great. It works perfectly!

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different approach altogether: add a temporary column to your data that contains a concatenation of each cell in the row. This way, you have:

```
A|B|C|D|E
1|Mr. Smith|500|A|1Mr. Smith500A
```

Then use Excel's conditional formatting on the temporary column, highlighting duplicate values. There you have your duplicated rows. Now it's only a matter of using a filter to check which ones have amounts equal to zero.

You can use the [CONCATENATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function; it requires you to specify each cell separately and you can't use a range, but in your case (comparing only some of the columns) it seems like a good fit.

Comment: Mmh... I see what you did here, and it's a really good idea. However, in my original file, there is no single item that doesn't have a match with the first criterias (bullet point list in the post). So everything will probably have a duplicate. What I need to highlight are the lines that cancel each other (line1+line2=0). Or maybe I misunderstood :)

Comment: I don't really understand which criteria you mean. If all rows match on one of the criteria, why not drop it?

Answer (score 1):

Maciej's answer is easy to implement (if you can add columns to your data without interrupting anything), and I would recommend it if possible.

However, for the sake of answering your question, I will contribute a VBA solution as well. I tested it on dataset that is a bit smaller than yours, but I think it will work for you. Note that you might have to tweak it a little (which row you start on, table name, etc) to fit your workbook.

Most notably, the segment commented with "Helper column" is something you most likely will have to adjust - currently, it compares every cell between A and H for the current row, which is something you may or may not want.

I've tried to include a little commentary in the code, but it's not much. The primary change is that I'm using in-memory processing of an array rather than iterating over a worksheet range (which for larger datasets should be exponentially faster).

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit
' Uses ref Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim xrow As Long, tCnt As Long
    Dim e As Range, f As Range, a As Range, j As Range, h As Range
    Dim sheetArr() As Variant, arr() As Variant
    Dim colorTheseYellow As New Dictionary, colorResults() As String, dictItem As Variant
    Dim arrSize As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Dim c As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    ws.Activate

    tCnt = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    xrow = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    ' Read range into an array so we process in-memory
    sheetArr = ws.Range("A2:H" & tCnt)
    arrSize = UBound(sheetArr, 1)

    ' Build new arr with "helper column"
    ReDim arr(1 To arrSize, 1 To 9)
    For i = 1 To arrSize
        For k = 1 To 8
            arr(i, k) = sheetArr(i, k)
            arr(i, 9) = CStr(arr(i, 9)) & CStr(arr(i, k)) ' "Helper column"
        Next k
    Next i

    ' Iterate over array & build collection to indicate yellow lines
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not colorTheseYellow.Exists(i) Then colorResults = Split(ReturnLines(arr(i, 9), arr), ";")
        For Each c In colorResults
            If Not colorTheseYellow.Exists(CLng(c)) Then colorTheseYellow.Add CLng(c), CLng(c)
        Next c
    Next i

    ' Enact row colors
    For Each dictItem In colorTheseYellow
        'Debug.Print "dict: "; dictItem
        If dictItem <> 0 Then ws.ListObjects(1).ListRows(CLng(dictItem)).Range.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Next dictItem
End Sub


Function ReturnLines(ByVal s As String, ByRef arr() As Variant) As String
    ' Returns a "Index;Index" string indicating the index/indices where the second, third, etc. instance(s) of s was found
    ' Returns "0;0" if 1 or fewer matches

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim tmp As String
    ReturnLines = 0
    j = 0
    tmp = "0"

    'Debug.Print "arg: " & s

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 9) = s Then
            j = j + 1
            'Debug.Print "arr: " & arr(i, 9)
            'Debug.Print "ReturnLine: " & i
            tmp = tmp & ";" & CStr(i)
        End If
    Next i

    'If Left(tmp, 1) = ";" Then tmp = Mid(tmp, 2, Len(tmp) - 1)

    'Debug.Print "tmp: " & tmp
    If j >= 2 Then
        ReturnLines = tmp
    Else
        ReturnLines = "0;0"
    End If
End Function
```

On my simple dataset, it yields this result (marked excellently with freehand-drawn color indicators):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I see what you did there and it should owrk, but I could get the macro to run for some reason.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, you will most likely have to adapt it a little. What part needs adapting depends what error you got (or what happened that wasn't supposed to happen).

Comment: Yes, you're right. And I think I found the line I forgot to edit before, thanks again I managed to make it work with this solution too !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers,

[Paul Bica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4914662/paul-bica)'s solution actually worked and I am using a version of this code now.

But, just to animate the debate, I think I also found another way around my first code, inspired by [Maciej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7240351/maciej-lipinski)'s idea of concatenating the cells and using **`CStr`** to compare the values and, of course [Vegard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604845/vegard)'s in-memory processing by using arrays instead of going through the workbook :

```vb
Sub Find_MatchesStr()

    Dim AmountArr(300) As Variant
    Dim rowArr(300) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    ws.Activate
    Range("A1").Select

    rCnt = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 2 To rCnt
        If i = rCnt Then
            Exit For
        Else
        intCnt = 0
        strA = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        strE = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
        strF = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
        strH = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
        strL = ws.Cells(i, 10).Value

        For j = i To rCnt - 1
            strSearchA = ws.Cells(j, 1).Value
            strSearchE = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value
            strSearchF = ws.Cells(j, 6).Value
            strSearchH = ws.Cells(j, 8).Value
            strSearchL = ws.Cells(j, 10).Value

            If CStr(strE) = CStr(strSearchE) And CStr(strA) = CStr(strSearchA) And CStr(strF) = CStr(strSearchF) And CStr(strH) = CStr(strSearchH) And CStr(strL) = CStr(strSearchL) Then

                AmountArr(k) = ws.Cells(j, 12).Value
                rowArr(k) = j
                intCnt = intCnt + 1
                k = k + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        strSum = 0
        For s = 0 To UBound(AmountArr)
            If AmountArr(s) <> "" Then
                strSum = strSum + AmountArr(s)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        strAppenRow = ""
        For b = 0 To UBound(rowArr)
            If rowArr(b) <> "" Then
                strAppenRow = strAppenRow & "" & rowArr(b) & "," & AmountArr(b) & ","
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If intCnt = 1 Then

        Else
            If strSum = 0 Then
                For rn = 0 To UBound(rowArr)
                    If rowArr(rn) <> "" Then
                        Let rRange = rowArr(rn) & ":" & rowArr(rn)
                        Rows(rRange).Select
                        Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                strvar = ""
                strvar = Split(strAppenRow, ",")
                For ik = 1 To UBound(strvar)
                    If strvar(ik) <> "" Then
                        strVal = CDbl(strvar(ik))
                        For ik1 = ik To UBound(strvar)
                            If strvar(ik1) <> "" Then
                                strVal1 = CDbl(strvar(ik1))
                                If strVal1 + strVal = 0 Then
                                    Let sRange1 = strvar(ik - 1) & ":" & strvar(ik - 1)
                                    Rows(sRange1).Select
                                    Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                                    Let sRange = strvar(ik1 - 1) & ":" & strvar(ik1 - 1)
                                    Rows(sRange).Select
                                    Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                                End If
                            Else
                                Exit For
                            End If
                            ik1 = ik1 + 1
                        Next
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    ik = ik + 1
                Next
            End If
        End If
        i = i + (intCnt - 1)
        k = 0
        Erase AmountArr
        Erase rowArr
        End If
    Next
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

I still have some mistakes (rows not higlighted when they should be), the above code is not perfect, but I thought it'd be OK to give you an idea of where I was going before Paul Bica's solution came in.

Thanks again !

Answer (score -2):

If your data is only till column L, then use below code, I found it is taking less time to run....

```
Sub Duplicates()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("O2") = "=A2&E2&F2&J2&L2"
    Range("P2") = "=COUNTIF(O:O,O2)"
    Range("O2:P" & lrow).FillDown
    Range("O2:O" & lrow).Copy
    Range("O2:O" & lrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    For i = 1 To lrow
        If Cells(i, 16) = 2 Then
            Cells(i, 16).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("O:P").Delete
    Range("A1").Select
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: You should format your code nicely, this is a mess. Have a look into the [help] for a how to.

Comment: You should also avoid copy and paste operations, as they are prone to producing errors in VBA